# C++ Unix Multithreading what happens "under the hood"?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, unix, c++11

I would like to know what happens "under the hood" with regards to C++ multithreading on Unix (specifically Linux)- particularly the involvement of the OS and semaphores etc.

I have performed an initial google search but it is not throwing up.

Could somebody please either describe or point me to a good resource that could help?

EDIT: When I create a thread in C++, what "objects" are created/stored by the operating system to manage this thread and any associated overheads involved?

Have realised this is more a Linux question than a C++ one.

Comment: Read about NPTL - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library. Non-Linux implementations will differ from this.

Comment: Linux uses the `clone()` system call to create schedulable execution contexts. Those are used both for spawning processes (via `fork()`) and threads (via pthreads).

Comment: If you are asking how the `clone()` system call is implemented, look [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.5/arch/mips/kernel/syscall.c#L97).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what threading library you're using.

In C++11, when you use `#include <thread>` the standard C++ library for your platform can choose to use OS-specific features. In the case of Linux this usually is accessed through pthreads, or in other cases direct calls to `clone(...)` with the appropriate flags and interactions via various `ioctls`, `fcntl`, and on some architectures atomic and memory model intrinsics (fences, barriers, etc.).

If you're using Boost.Thread in C++03 mode you're basically using pthreads under the hood. All of the constructs in Boost.Thread in POSIX operating systems rely on POSIX threading primitives.

Comment: Hi Dean, i'm not sure if I asked my question correctly, but its possible my Q is more OS-orientated. I am interested in how the thread "entities" are created and managed under the hood. When I create a thread, what else is being created and stored to monitor the thread?

Comment: I'm confused. I thought you were asking how threading in C++ used OS-level facilities to achieve multi-threading.

Comment: I'm more interested in: "when I write a thread in C++, what is happening under the bonnet?" I am interested in what entities are created/stores by the OS, how are the threads managed etc? What is used to define the boundaries of a thread? I *think* its more OS-orientated... So basically if someone asked you what happens when somebody creates a thread, you would know what is going on "under the bonnet"

Comment: This is exactly what I and others have pointed out. You need to look at the clone() function call and other related control functions provided by the kernel through system calls. If you want, you can dive into the Linux kernel code to see how it creates the memory structures and details of how it schedules these things. Otherwise the answer addresses your question I believe sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your program with the help of "strace". This will list all system calls made to the operating system.